# Can't run delete query

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to run a delete query

```
DELETE tblInventory.ProductNo, tblInventory.Vendor
FROM tblInventory
WHERE (((tblInventory.Vendor) Like "*barshop*"));
```

I'm getting the following error message though.

CaseTracker can't delete 1 record(s) in the delete query due to key violations 0 record(s) due to lock violations.

What do I need to do to make the query run?

Answer (score 1):

I may try something like this:

`DELETE 
FROM tblInventory 
WHERE tblInventory.Vendor LIKE '%barshop%'`

That's the case if you're using SQL Server. Not sure that runs on MS-Access DB

In the DELETE statement you are deleting a complete record that matches your WHERE statement, so you don't need to put columns like in a SELECT statement.

Hope it helps.

Comment: OP says MS access, so the like wildcard would be the asterisk --> http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/like.php. But +1 for answering the question :-)